# Calculating Total from interest, principle and years using FOR LOOP

Tags: python, for-loop

I am trying to create a program that asks the user their principal, interest rate, and total amount of years. I want my program to show them the amount of total return they would expect for each year. I want it to start at year 1. When I run my script, it only shows one year's worth total interest. Here is what I have so far.

```
#Declare the necessary variables.
princ = 0
interest = 0.0
totYears = 0
year = 1

#Get the amont of principal invested.
print("Enter the principal amount.")
princ = int(input())

#Get the interest rate being applied.
print("Enter the interest rate.")
interest = float(input())

#Get the total amount of years principal is invested.
print ("Enter the total number of years you're investing this amonut.")
totYears = int(input())

for years in range(1, totYears):
    total=year*interest*princ
    years += 1

print (total)
```

Thank you any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please quit posting problem updates and new problems as answers!  Edit them into the question body, or post as separate questions.

Comment: My apologies! This is my first time using this. I will repost as new question. I tried to incorporate your advice but I am still having the issue of the year counter starting at 5 (or whichever value you choose for totYear).

Answer (score 1):

There are problems here:

```
for years in range(1, totYears):
    total=year*interest*princ
    years += 1

print (total)
```

1. You change **years** within the loop.  Don't.  The **for** statement takes care of that for you.  Your interference makes **years** change by 2 each time through the loop.
2. Every time through the loop, you throw away the previous year's interest and compute a new one.  Your print statement is outside the loop, so you print only the final value of **total**.
3. Your loop index is **years**, but you've computed on the variable **year**, which is always **1**.  A programming technique I picked up many years ago is never to use a plural variable name.

Perhaps you need this:

```
for years in range(1, totYears):
    total = years * interest * princ
    print (total)
```

Comment: Thanks, that clarified things. However how do I get it to show the interest accrued per each year as a table would. For instance, year 1 = 500, year 2 =1000, year 3=2000, etc. Mine shows the final interest over the total number of years and repeats it four times.

Comment: Put the print statement inside the loop, just like I showed in that last block of code above.

Comment: Shouldn't the totYears be starting at year 1 and above according to my range(totYears)? For example, when I input totYears as 5, it start calculating from 5 to 10 years. How do I fix this?

Comment: No.  **years** runs from 1 to (but not including) **totYears**.  The code you posted (and my update) both run 1 through 4.  I have no idea why it's running 5 through 10; you haven't posted that code.

Comment: Thank you, I should clarify the code and be more consistent. I only changed a few suggestions that you gave me. I was not sure how to post the updated code as a comment. So I will either answer below or create a new question. My apologies, I am new to this whole thing. Cheers!